# SQL select features in a polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, select

I have the following code which works fine:

```
select vissoort, count(1), ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5.341248 51.615590)',4326):: geography, 2500)
from   visvangsten
where  st_intersects(visvangsten.locatie,
ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5.3412480 51.615590)',4326):: geography, 2500))
group by vissoort
order by 2 desc
```

Now I want the same function but then selecting the features within a polygon instead of the circle/buffer.

I tried things like this but nothing worked:

```
select vissoort, count(1), ST_asText( ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592)'::geometry, 4326) )
from   visvangsten
where  st_contains(ST_asText( ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592)'::geometry, 4326) ), visvangsten.locatie);
group by vissoort
order by 2 desc limit 1
```

The database table looks like this:

```
  id ([PK]bigint) | datum(date) | vissoort(character varying) | locatie(geometry) 
------------------|-------------|-----------------------------|------------------
      15729       |  2007-06-23 |           Blankvoorn        |  0101000...etc.
------------------|-------------|-----------------------------|------------------
       etc.       |    etc.     |              etc.           |       etc.
```

Does someone know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ; at the end of

```
where  st_contains(ST_asText( ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592)'::geometry, 4326) ), visvangsten.locatie);
```

You also have to close your polygon.  Change it to something like:

```
ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592, 5.303 51.629)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it and got the following error:

ERROR:  lwpoly_from_lwlines: shell must be closed
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_polygon" statement 1
SQL state: XX000

Comment: Alright now i have the following code: select vissoort, count(1), ST_asText( ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592, 5.303 51.629)'::geometry, 4326) )
from   visvangsten
where  st_contains(ST_asText( ST_Polygon('LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592, 5.303 51.629)'::geometry, 4326) ), visvangsten.locatie);
group by vissoort
order by 2 desc limit 1

and the error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 4: group by vissoort
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 337

Comment: You still have a semi-colon in the middle of your query.  You can only have one at the end

Comment: Oops sorry i removed it: ERROR:  contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Polygon, 0) != (Point, 4326)
SQL state: XX000

Answer (score 0):

The following code was the answer:

```
select vissoort, count(1), ST_MakePolygon('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592, 5.303 51.629)'::geometry)
from visvangsten
where st_contains(ST_MakePolygon('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(5.303 51.629, 5.387 51.626, 5.393 51.588, 5.281 51.592, 5.303 51.629)'::geometry) , visvangsten.locatie)
group by vissoort
order by 2 desc
```